# Arbitrage-Free implied/local volatility surface with Cubic Spline Interpolation

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, local-volatility, volatility-surface, interpolation

I am trying to create a local volatility surface using a cubic spline interpolated implied volatility surface. In other words, I have a function $\sigma(T,K)$, that is arbitrage-free $\forall T,K$ (even for strikes and maturities that aren't listed). This way, I can calculate $\frac{\partial^2 \sigma(T,K)}{\partial K^2}$ and $\frac{\partial \sigma(T,K)}{\partial T}$ numerically at any point along the surface with an $\epsilon \approx 10^{-5}$ i.e.
$$\frac{\partial \sigma(T,K)}{\partial T}=\frac{\sigma(T+\epsilon,K) - \sigma(T-\epsilon,K)}{2\epsilon}$$

and then be able to create the local volatility surface at any point I want, and not be constrained to specific maturities and strikes.

I have implemented [Fengler's (2005)](https://core.ac.uk/reader/6978470) version, but this just creates new nodes for new implied volatilities. Similarly with the SVI approach by [Gatheral (2013)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf), does it not just create new implied vol *points* and not a "continuous" arbitrage-free surface?

Basically, I am trying to create a spline object (can be cubic, linear or any type) from the griddata, then use something like `scipy.interpolate.Rbf(T, K, IV ,func='cubic')` and then for any `T,K` there won't be arbitrage.

Is this actually possible? Intuitively, I think it’s not because the best-fit cubic spline created from `scipy.interpolate` that is between 2 arb-free options on the same smile will be concave every 2nd option, resulting in $\frac{\partial^2 \sigma(T,K)}{\partial K^2} < 0$ at those points.

Comment: You could try it at a single maturity maybe (and observe the fit)? Because each cubic spline is fitted for a local vol smile/skew right?

Comment: @KaiSqDist I tried and some $K$ break butterfly arbitrage. From what I understand, each missing strike on each skew is fitted using a cubic spline. But the parameters of the cubic spline do not guarantee no arb for other points on that spline. I.e. if you have 5 strikes but want to interpolate for 7, there would be 4 splines on the sub-intervals of your 5 strikes, and those splines would satisfy butterfly arb at those specific 7 strikes, but not all strikes on the spline. So you can’t just choose a random strike on the spline. I could be wrong, but that’s how I have understood these papers.

Comment: @KaiSqDist The interpolated strike that satisfies the no-arb condition would be in the convex domain of the cubic spline, which gives $\sigma_{KK}>0$, but for concave domain of the spline, we get $\sigma_{KK}<0$. I’m more so asking if I’m wrong here or if there is a way to remedy it so there can be a continuous no-arb spline